# Globalization vs. Localization

Tags: localization, globalization

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Terminology used for language and culture-aware software](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/384038/terminology-used-for-language-and-culture-aware-software)
>   [What is system.globalization And what’s the difference between it and localization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/278136/what-is-system-globalization-and-whats-the-difference-between-it-and-localizatio)

What is the difference between Globalization and Localization?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/384038/terminology-used-for-language-and-culture-aware-software

Comment: @Nemanja: I think this is a nice simple comparison, as the other question you listed is very difficult to follow.

Comment: @Jherico, I don't know how you haven't gotten an upvote before now, but that was clever and amused me.

Answer (score 42):

Straight from MSDN:

> Globalization is the process of
> designing and developing applications
> that function for **multiple cultures.**
>
> Localization is the process of
> **customizing** your application for a
> **given culture and locale**.

...Globalization focuses your applications capibilities on users as a generic user-base, whereas localization focuses on subsets of users in a given culture or locale.  So you can think of globalization as a strategic venue, where as localization is tactical.

[MSDN Globalization vs. Localization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c6zyy3s9.aspx)

Answer (score 22):

Globalization is making your software ready for international markets:

- Format and parse numbers, dates etc. according to the user's locale
- Handle international text
- ...
- Making your software localizable

Localization is adapting your software to a particular local market:

- Providing translations for text messages in your software
- Sometimes adjusting screen layout to fit longer text

Answer (score 15):

Localisation is things like changing the user interface to be in differing languages; Globalisation (or internationalisation) is about being able to handle foreign content, such as being able to load a Japanese document on a English machine/build of the application.

Comment: explanation which is digestible